# Problem with detecting scroll position in react

Tags: reactjs, events, scroll

I'm making a effect similar to FullPage.js (like scroll-snap css)

For that, I defined a state for scroll position
and when scrolling down, I made it move to component automatically
using window.scrollTo.

```
const Page = () => {
  const [pos, setPos] = useState(0);
  const target = useRef();
  const [snap,setSnap] = useState(false);

  const onScroll = () => {
    setPos(window.scrollY);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll',onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll",onScroll);
    }
  },[]);
  
  ...

  if (snap) { // if snap turns true then move to component
    target.current.scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Component ref={traget}>
        ..
      </Component>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

This code works. But it moves too slowly.
I think defining a state for scroll position
call re-render. might not be that..

Could you tell me how can I solve this?